# Keyring doesn't stay unlocked

Tags: ssh, keyrings, gnome-keyring

This is a new machine where I installed Ubuntu 22.04. Whenever I unlock my keyring to log into some server via SSH, it does not stay unlocked. This is particularly annoying when running an Ansible script where it will ask me to unlock the keyring on multiple steps, rather than just asking once per session (like it does on my other machine).

A) Why is this and, B) How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured this out. This happened because I was actually using i3wm session and the ssh-agent doesn't automatically start.

What I ended up doing is to add `eval $(ssh-agent)` to my `~.profile` file, and now it starts whenever I log into my i3wm session. I only need to enter the ssh password once now, and everything works as I'm used to.